# Filling the tableView with existing data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, core-data

I am at the first step of developing an app about solving some engineering problems, i have about 30 topics that should be listed in a table (like a dictionary app) and user can select one of them or searching between them and then after touching on one of them, it goes to another page to get data and solve the problem. To be more clear, i don't want to get any data from user and user just need to select an item between 30 items in a table.

Since i am completely a beginner developer, i think about two options and i don't know which one is better (or maybe both of them is a bad or wrong idea)

First is making an entities in CoreData, then adding a attributes inside it. For example with the name of "NameOfTopics". And then i add the names to this attributes to show in the tableview

second one is making an array and adding all of the names inside the array and then send them to Tableview.

Which one is better? Or there is a better way? 
i would be appreciated you to help me in advance

Comment: If the data is static, then an array is fine (implement TableViewDataSource in your UITableViewController subclass).  If the data is dynamic, a backing storage like CoreData is more appropriate.

Comment: @DavidS. Thank you very much for your help. They are static.
but one more thing, i want to let user to bookmark any topic that they want to access them faster. does it need CoreData? If yes, the way that i say for using coreData is right? I mean this way: First is making an entities in CoreData, then adding a attributes inside it. For example with the name of "NameOfTopics". And then i add the names to this attributes to show in the tableview

Comment: The template iOS project shows you have to use Core Data if you enable "Use Core Data" in the setup wizard and pick the "Master Detail" template.  There is a data model file where you declare an Entity and its properties.  There is a NSFetchedResultsController which handles the queries into Core Data.  And there's an object context for querying and persisting data.

Comment: @DavidS. Thank you so much, i really appreciate it.